# Can't use cookie in frontend but works fine in postman

Tags: java, cookies, fetch, postman, localhost

I've created rest API in springboot that upon sending valid credentials returns jwt access token and saves refresh token in httpOnly cookie, when I send GET request to the API that uses cookie in postman it works just fine but when I try to fetch in react API returns error that indicates that there is no cookies

> error_message: "Cannot read the array length because "array" is null"

So do I have to specify domain name If yes how do I do it while working on localhost (springboot is working on `localhost:8080` and react `localhost:3000`).

**How I currently create cookie:**

```
public static Cookie createRefreshCookie(String refresh_token) {
        Cookie jwtRefreshCookie = new Cookie("refresh_token", refresh_token);
        jwtRefreshCookie.setMaxAge(2678400);
        jwtRefreshCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        jwtRefreshCookie.setPath("/");
        return jwtRefreshCookie;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was caused by my fetch request in react that contained header `withCredentials: true` from library axios insead of fetch implementation of header `credentials:"include"`.